# How to get all possible orders of comma separated strings

Tags: r, algorithm, dataframe, permutation

I tried searching for the R problem but couldn't find anything useful.

I have a dataframe like this:

```
Post_ID New_Mentions_1      New_Mentions_2
   1          model                      
   2      telephone          louis vuitton
   3           uber          employee
   4   united states                      
   5          onion         pepper, rice, garlic
```

And my expected result is expanding the dataframe with all possible orders of New_Mention_2

```
 Post_ID New_Mentions_1      New_Mentions_2
   1          model                      
   2      telephone           louis vuitton
   3           uber            employee
   4   united states                      
   5          onion        pepper,rice,garlic
   5          onion        rice,garlic,pepper
   5          onion        garlic,pepper,rice
   5          onion        pepper,garlic,rice
   5          onion        garlic,rice,pepper
   5          onion        rice,pepper,garlic
```

Please help me with a program for this. I also have few rows with 5 keywords separated by commas.

Comment: This is a curious requirement. Why do you need all possible permutations of those items?

Answer (score 0):

There should be an easier way to deal with this, but I can't seem to find it.

To make sure we're talking about the same dataframe, I repost your data:

```
df <- structure(list(New_Mentions_1 = c("model", "telephone", "uber", 
        "united_states", "onion"), New_Mentions_2 = c(NA, "louis_vuitton", 
        "employee", NA, "pepper,rice,garlic")), .Names = c("New_Mentions_1", 
        "New_Mentions_2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

First you check which rows in `df` have multiple values in the `New_Mentions_2` column, using `grep`. This functions returns the rows in which your second column contains a comma-value. Then we split the data frame in the part that doesn't need fixing (i.e. has no comma values in the second column) and call it `newdf`. The part that needs fixing is called `subdf`.

We'll mess around (details below the code) a bit with `subdf` to get all possible combinations of the values and append the results to the `newdf` data frame:

```
library(gtools)
# Which rows in df have multiple values in the second column?
inds <- grep(pattern = ",", df$New_Mentions_2)

subdf <- df[inds, ]
newdf <- df[-inds, ]

# Just in case you have multiple 'problematic' rows, we'll loop through all of them
for(i in 1:nrow(subdf)){
  splitted <- strsplit(subdf$New_Mentions_2[i], ", ")[[1]]
  n        <- length(splitted)
  shuffled <- permutations(n, n)
  for(j in 1:nrow(shuffled)){
    val_2 <- paste(splitted[shuffled[j, ]], collapse = ", ")
    val_1 <- subdf$New_Mentions_1[i]
    newdf <- rbind(newdf, c(val_1, val_2))
  }
}
```

The 'messing around' part is performed mostly in the outer loop. Firstly, the value of e.g. "pepper, rice, garlic" is split for every `,` (comma + space). `splitted` will then contain `c("pepper", "rice", "garlic")`, for which we get all possible combinations using the `permutations` function from the gtools-package. In the first line of the inner-loop, the shuffled strings will be put back together into a single string (`paste()` with the `collapse = ", ")` argument), so that we can fit them in one column of a data frame again.